# Vector subspace, what dimension could it be?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new here and hope that I can help also others with questions, but now I have one, I was three weeks sick and wasn't often in the university and now I'm just wondering how to do my task.

Let  $U$, $V$ and $W$ be $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^6$ with

$$U + V = U ⊕ V,\quad U + W = U ⊕ W,\quad\text{and}\quad V + W = V ⊕ W$$

What dimension could $U+V+W$ have?

Here we should give a example but how I do that? Can give someone me some tips?

I have also another task which is really similar.

Let $U$, $V$ and $W$ be $1$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with

$$U + V = U ⊕ V,\quad U + W = U ⊕ W,\quad\text{and}\quad V + W = V ⊕ W$$
but $U + V + W ≠ U ⊕ V ⊕ W$

Also here I should give a example and explain why.

So please can give me someone a tip? 
Thanks from now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the former: we know that $\dim(U + V) = \dim(U\oplus V) = 4$, so $U + V + W$ has dimension at least 4. Indeed, it can also be exactly four: with $e_1$ through $e_6$ the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^6$, take $U = \langle e_1, e_2\rangle$, $V = \langle e_3,e_4\rangle$, $W = \langle e_1+e_3,e_2+e_4\rangle$, and note that $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ is a basis for $U + V + W = U + V = U + W = V + W$. On the other side, $U + V + W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^6$, so $\dim (U + V + W) \leq 6$. It should be easy to construct examples where $\dim U$ is each of $5$ and $6$.

The example I gave also satisfies your second question.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1**

> $U + V + W$ has Dimension at most $6$.

**Hint 2**

> $U + V  + W$ has Dimension at least $4$, as it contains...

**Hint 3**

> Start with $U, V$, and try and construct an example with $W \subseteq U + V$.

**Hint 4**

> In $W$ you may try and put suitable elements of the form $u + v$, with $0 \ne u \in U$, $0 \ne v \in V$.